# Can a virtual machine be as efficient as a hardware based OS?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, parallel-processing, virtual-machine

I am forgoing dual booting for the ease of a virtual machine and I have a few questions which I am unable to find answers to online. Could someone answer these, or at least point me in the right direction to find out details about how a virtual machine might be able to utilize full hardware power?

I am going to be running Windows 8 (natively) and using a VM to run a flavor of Linux (probably Ubuntu 12.04.2 if it matters).

(1) Will my virtual machine be able to run my Fortran in Parallel?
- I have a Intel Core i7 2.4 GHz processor which has the ability to hyperthread up to 8 cores. If I run code in the VM using MPI/pthreads/openMP, will I be able to utilize the 4 physical cores? How about the hyperthreading 8 cores?
- Will there be a slow down of the 2.4 GHz? I assume there will be some since they need to also run Windows, but how horribly will it be affected?

(2) I have a dedicated GPU (GeForce GTX 770M), will I be able to use the dedicated GPU for CUDA based (or OpenCL, or any kind of GPGPU) programming?

(3) I am starting out with 4 GB or RAM, but plan on upgrading to 16 GB. I know that the RAM will affect the VM, but will it be the dominate thing which affects VM performance? Once I upgrade to the full 16 GB of RAM, will I be able to consider any other inefficiencies to be negligible?

Thanks for the help ahead of time. Again, even pointing me in the right direction for reading will help if full answers cannot be given.

Comment: (2) Maybe when "device fission" for gpu is introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) VMWare supports multiple cores and hyperthreading. You can choose how many to assign to the VM. The physical processor isn't slowed down, but obviously your host OS will be using some CPU too, and the virtualization has an overhead (albeit small on modern CPUs).

(2) You'll need to check that out for the particular virtual machine software and version.

(3) RAM works in a pretty obvious way: the host OS uses some, the guest OS some, and VMWare's overhead is an order of magnitude smaller. 4 GB is enough to run Ubuntu in Windows, but if you want multiple VMs or are running processes that use gigabytes, add a corresponding amount of RAM.

I've used VMWare Workstation for years, plus VirtualBox recently. I'd say that for high end or leading edge stuff, VMWare is still the better choice. For easier tasks VirtualBox is nice.